# Priority of onclick and $("#abc").click(function(){}), which precedence is higher?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `onclick` function on `<button>` as well as `$("#abc").click(function(){})`, on same button.
I want the seconds one's priority more higher then the first one in JQuery, how I can do that ?

Comment: I would stick to one or the other and then chain the execution of methods as required. It will be easier to maintain and you will get explicit control of the execution order. Which would I pick, the unobtrusive event handler, i.e. jQuery, but note you can do similar without jQuery.

Comment: The question is that how i can change this priority ?

Comment: You can't change it. This is why you need to remove the inline `onclick` and roll it into the `jQuery` handler. The only reason not to do this is if you cannot modify the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` in the HTML tag will get executed first and then the code in the jquery click handler. Here is an example fiddle [Order of click events](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/614986/)

Comment: How i can change this ?

Comment: Handlers are executed in the order of registration. So a handler in the HTML will always be registered first and execute first. But, why do you want to change that? and what is the reason to have click handlers defined at 2 places. It might give rise to unexpected issues.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is that everything you set in the element itself goes first, or overwrites everything (like with style). It always has the highest precedence.

The functionality in the `onClick` (and `onBlur` etc) go first, then the other events are fired in the order they are set.